# cant get model info from caret model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

cant get model info from caret model in R for linear model i can just use the summary function however for this caret ridge model i got strange information
this is what i got when i run summary

```
actions      8     -none-     list     
allset       7     -none-     numeric  
beta.pure   56     -none-     numeric  
vn           7     -none-     character
mu           1     -none-     numeric  
normx        7     -none-     numeric  
meanx        7     -none-     numeric  
lambda       1     -none-     numeric  
L1norm       8     -none-     numeric  
penalty      8     -none-     numeric  
df           8     -none-     numeric  
Cp           8     -none-     numeric  
sigma2       1     -none-     numeric  
xNames       7     -none-     character
problemType  1     -none-     character
tuneValue    1     data.frame list     
obsLevels    1     -none-     logical  
param        1     -none-     list
```

i alos tried $finalmodel and did not get any info

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have some caret model object like `gbmFit1` in [this caret tutorial](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#model-training-and-parameter-tuning). I used this code and created the following small linear model example which worked:

```
#require package
require(caret)

#use iris data frame as training data
(training <- iris[, 1:4])

#set fit control
fitControl <- trainControl( #10-fold CV
  method = "repeatedcv"
  ,number = 10
  ,repeats = 10) #repeated ten times

#train model
lmFit1 <- train(
  Sepal.Length ~ .
  ,data = training
  ,method = "lm" #set method to linear model
  ,trControl = fitControl
  ,verbose = FALSE)

#inspect model
lmFit1$finalModel
summary(lmFit1)
```

Here I do get an output for `lmFit1$finalModel` as well as for `summary(lmFit1)`. So I assume that either your caret model is very different from `lmFit1` or maybe something went wrong when your model was calculated.

You can inspect the structure of every object in R using the `str()` function. Many model objects in R turn out to be a `list`, so does caret model object `lmFit1`. Here is some exemplary R-code you can use to further inspect your caret model object:

```
#structure of the model object, which is a list
str(lmFit1)

#inspect structure of first list item of the model object
str(lmFit1[[1]])

#show first list item of the model object
lmFit1[[1]]

#inspect structure of second list item of the model object
str(lmFit1[[2]])

#...
```